# Nested pojo java class - What could I make better

Tags: java, json, lombok

I need code review. I've used Lombok and jackson. Static statemts look very "ugly" in Root class. I don't know what I should make with that. Is There another way to create nested classes?

Main class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Root.CreditCard creditCard = new Root.CreditCard();
        creditCard.setName("ttt card");
        creditCard.setUrl("www.test.com");

        Root.ArrayBrowser arrayBrowser = new Root.ArrayBrowser();
        arrayBrowser.setUrl("array 1 url");
        arrayBrowser.setName("array 1 name");
        List<Root.ArrayBrowser> arrayBrowserList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayBrowserList.add(arrayBrowser);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setName("root name");
        root.setUrl("root url");
        root.setCreditCard(creditCard);
        root.setArrayBrowser(arrayBrowserList);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(root));
    }
}
```

And pojo class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Root {
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private CreditCard creditCard;
    private List<ArrayBrowser> arrayBrowser;

    @Data
    public static class CreditCard {
        private String name;
        private String url;
    }

    @Data
    public static class ArrayBrowser {
        private String name;
        private String url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if the request of code review could be improved I don't understand why somebody downvoted the post. It is not very welcoming.

Answer (score 1):

This is very borderline not reviewable. The data class alone without any context is difficult to review and the class and field names look placeholdery. Why "`Root`" and "`ArrayBrowser`"?

First about your remarks:

> I've used Lombok and jackson.

No, you are using GSON. The import and use of the Jackson exception is pointless (unless GSON throws it, which I doubt).

> Static statemts look very "ugly" in Root class. [...] Is There another way to create nested classes?

There is nothing wrong with how you are using the nested classes (unless you are using them somewhere else). Why are you using nested classes if you don't like how they look?

Consider using constructors which set all fields (Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor`) which can make building the classes easier instead if calling all the setters.

Also consider using immutable classes (Lombok's `@Value` instead of `@Data`), especially if your only use is to write JSON.